# get combination of special characters

Tags: mysql, character, combinations

I have a table like this:

- name
- A1B2
- A2D2
- A1C4

I want to get all combination of (A,C,D) such that:
found
A2D2
A1C4

just having (A,C,D) not other characters..

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you need only A, C, D characters in name and not other characters like 1, 2 etc. you could try REGEXP:

```
select * from names where name REGEXP '^(A|C|D)+$';
```

If the combination of A,B and numeric characters is needed you may use regex `^[AB0-9]+$` . Try this test:

```
select 'A1B2' REGEXP '^[AB0-9]+$';
```

Comment: Thanks,,, and if the initial table change like A1B2,B2C3,C1A2...., then how can i get all combinations of (A,B)? like A1B2, B2A1, etc....so that A not necessarily comes at first?